# Group by column pairs without considering their order

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table like this:

| Name1 | Name2 | Address1 | Address2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Mary | 1st Street | 2nd Street |
| Mary | Jane | 2nd Street | 1st Street |
| Aubery | Mary | 3rd Street | 2nd Street |
| Sindy | Simon | 4th Street | 5th Street |

I would like row 1 and 2 to be captured as the same in a `GROUP BY` statement, that is, row 1 and 2 represents the same information but in a different order (So their count would be 2) with the two pairs being `Name1, Address1` & `Name2, Address2`.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can aggregate using a `LEAST`/`GREATEST` trick:

```sql
SELECT
    LEAST(Name1, Name2) AS Name1,
    GREATEST(Name1, Name2) AS Name2,
    LEAST(Address1, Address2) AS Address1,
    GREATEST(Address1, Address2) AS Address2,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Amazing, it works perfectly. Would you be able to explain the trick in a simple way I can follow up on? (Sorry just starting in SQL)

Comment: @Jack `LEAST()` takes the smaller of two inputs.  So `LEAST(3, 5)` and `LEAST(5, 3)` always produces 3, etc.  Apply this logic to two names and addresses, and it de-duplicates your data.